# Django - Custom tag not working

Tags: django

I want to pass a model to template base.html.

I read about custom tags, and tried to execute this. It is not throwing any error, but is not working too.

My code:

base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load tags %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            {% for league in get_my_leagues %}
            <li> ddddd {{ league.league_name }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
         </ul>

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, tags.py:

```
from django.template import Library
from login.models import League

register = Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('base.html')
def get_my_leagues():
    return League.objects.all()

register.tag('get_my_leagues', get_my_leagues)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply load your leagues in `views.py` and pass them to your template?

Comment: @Chris I just do not know how do it with views, and pass to base template

Comment: Okay, so there are really _two_ questions here: (a) why doesn't what you did above work, and (b) is there a simpler way to do this? Let's focus on (a) first. You say it doesn't throw any errors. What _does_ happen? Does the template render without any leagues in it?

Comment: Yes, @Cris. The template is rendered, but does not show any data.

Comment: You should really consider reading the Django tutorial, and implement this functionality in your view.

Comment: If this is something that is supposed to appear in the base template which is inherited by every other template in the application, then a template tag is indeed the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: I've just added an answer for the first question (and somebody else gave one a few seconds later). Since Stack Overflow [works best with one question per post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/248627) I suggest you submit a new question about how to pass `leagues` directly from `views.py`. This may be a cleaner solution.

Comment: @koniiiik , I think a custom context processor would be even more elegant...But either works.

Comment: @mevius: Custom template tags vs. context processors is partly a matter of taste, but yes, if this is specific to a single project, and not part of a reusable application, a context processor would work, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys.

I'm here just to tell that i found a solution for my problem. I'm using Context Processors to do this job.

Thank you all for answers!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `{% for x in y %}`, this expects that `y` is a context variable in your template, not a template tag.

What an inclusion tag does is that it renders a template (the one you pass as argument to the `inclusion_tag` decorator), and inserts the result where the inclusion tag is used.

You probably want to register `get_my_leagues` as a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) instead (or an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags), if you're using Django older than 1.9), and use it like this:

```
{% get_my_leagues as my_leagues %}
{% for league in my_leagues %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Note that Django 1.9 deprecates `assignment_tag` in favour of `simple_tag`.

Comment: Indeed, as is written right where I pointed the link. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi, @koniiiik,

When I follow your advice, the browser returns me this error:
https://s24.postimg.org/mzvxoorut/1.png

Comment: How did you register the tag? Could you posted the updated definition of your tag?